# How to refresh view using DBT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt, datamart

I couldn't find any docs about refresh view. Like i did using SQL on PostgreSQL `REFRESH MARTERILZED VIEW`

```
dbt run # create view/table
dbt refresh ?
```

There no option for refresh view that created by dbt right?

Comment: A regular view [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) and [MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) are two different things. You `REFRESH` the latter but not the former. In other words a regular view is always 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

to refresh a materialized view you could add sql header like below on the any model that want to reference it:

```
    {{
        config(
          ...
              ,
          sql_header="REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name;"
      
        )
    }}
```